# How to find what serial number a user has in Twitter

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I would like to follow certain users just to monitor their tweets in my program, but I don't know where to find the serial numbers that identify Twitter users.  I have

```
follow_list = []
streamer.filter(follow = follow_list)
```

I know that the users are identified by strings like `'1234567890'`, but I don't know where a list of these serial numbers is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use twitter's `users/lookup` [API method](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup), it will take usernames and return list of dicts with extended user data.

In tweepy there is `lookup_users` method, wrapping this API call. According to tweepy source, it should be somethin like:

```
users = tweepy.api.lookup_users(screen_names=['twitter', 'cleg'])
for user in users:
    print(user)
```

Comment: How do I executed this lookup_users method though?

Comment: Added example. It can be not precisely correct, as I don't have tweepy installed, but it should give you an idea.